# How does GetModuleHandle work in Visual c++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am new to c++ and this code always returns NULL even though i know the file exists:

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\stub.exe"));
```

Interestingly, if i copy stub.exe to C:\Windows\system32, it finds the module with this code:

```
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("stub.exe"));
```

Am i missing something incredibly basic?

Comment: note that GetModuleHandle is not a part of C++, it's a Win32 API function. You can call it from every other language that supports calling the OS API directly. Fixed tags accordingly.

Comment: Try calling GetModuleFilename with an hModule of 0; that will tell you what Windows thinks the path to your executable is. I suspect it's subtly different to the string you're passing in some way.

Comment: Why do you need that handle anyway? The common case is with `GetProcAddress`, but that's for DLLs not EXEs.

Comment: @MSalters You need it for `LoadImage`, `TaskDialogIndirect` etc., and in general anything that wants to load a resource. But you are quite right that GetModuleHandle(NULL) is most likely what OP wants here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only call `GetModuleHandle(L"C:\\Users\\Steve\\Desktop\\stub.exe");` when you're running `C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\stub.exe`.

But in general, you don't call `GetModuleHandle` for your EXE name. Since there's only one EXE per process, you just call `GetModuleHandle(0)`.

Comment: An EXE can export functions and be linked with just as well as a DLL. It is not a common case, but still a possibility.

Comment: `GetModuleHandle(0)` will return the PE of the current DLL you are currently in, not the parent EXE.. so its not a useful function for this purpose.. I also have this problem. I think you have to use `GetCurrentProcess()`

Comment: Actually `GetModuleHandle(0)` will return a handle to the .exe.

Copied directly from MSDN "If this parameter is NULL, **GetModuleHandle** returns a handle to the file used to create the calling process (.exe file)."

Unless Microsoft has changed the documentation recently.

Comment: @Bja: No change, this has been the case since Win32. How would the OS even know which DLL made the `GetModuleHandle(0)` call?

Comment: @MSalters: My comment was actually in response to SSpoke, who seems to have the wrong idea of how it actually works. They were the ones that stated `GetModuleHandle(0)` returns the DLL instance you are currently in, not me. I know MS hasn't changed the documentation or changed how the function works, I am not one to reply to a year old comment saying "you are wrong" when after that time no one else has. I should have changed my last line to " Unless Microsoft has changed the documentation recently (which I highly doubt)". Never mind, I now understand it is in regards to a linked EXE.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, [`GetModuleHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) requires that you load the dll into the process before hand.

Windows has specific paths that it uses to search for modules, as well as some switches to force 'safe' dll loading, you may want to look into `SetDllDirectory` and `AddDllDirectory` if you wish to expand the locations searched. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for an explanation of how Windows search for binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683199%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

> ### GetModuleHandle Function
>
> Retrieves a module handle for the specified module. The module must have been loaded by the calling process.

This means that you have to load the module with [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) first. System32 might get special treatment, but you really should not be copying anything there. The folder is strictly for the operating system's usage.