# GetModuleHandle fails to find module

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I've already used both GetLastError() and FormatError(), the message always shows the module couldn't be found.

However, while I can't find the module I want to (which is "example.exe"), I can find those who are Windows-related that were also loaded by the app. I've found a couple of them and yep, the problem is with the example.exe (and one more dll).

However, all the Windows-related dlls are on my C drive while example.exe and another dll which I failed to find as well are on my E drive. Could it be the problem? I've tried to change vs to multibyte and not set, no success. I've tried GetModuleHandleA, GetModuleHandleW, no success.

Here, a snippet:

```
DWORD64 pattern_scan(const char* Module, const char* pattern, const char* mask) {
    MODULEINFO modInfo = { 0 };
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleA(Module);
    if (!(hModule)) {
        std::cout << Module << std::endl;
        std::cout << GetLastErrorAsString();
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: See the [how-does-getmodulehandle-work-in-visual-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728782/how-does-getmodulehandle-work-in-visual-c).
Does it work with GetModuleHandle( NULL );    //NULL == 0

Comment: You don't show this _"...The module must have been loaded by the calling process...."_ in your [mcve].  How is `"example.exe"` loaded or is it your currently running program?

Comment: @RichardCritten It is loaded, I checked all the modules loaded by the app through another function.

Comment: How was `"example.exe"` loaded? What was the exact string passed to `pattern_scan` ? The requirements for `GetModuleHandleA` are precise regarding the passed module name see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlea

Comment: `GetLastErrorAsString` is useless. It's (presumably) calling `GetLastError`. And it does so **way** too late. At that point, the value is meaningless.

Comment: Are you trying to find module handles in the executing process, or in a different process